# The character group is an algebraic group.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, cw-complexes

Let $X$ be a finite dimensional connected CW complex. Let $G=\pi_1(X)$.
Let $\hat G=Hom(G,\mathbb C^*)$ the character group of $G$.
Then $\hat G$ is an affine algebraic group. Could someone explain why this is true, i cannot relate $\hat G$ to any set of zeros of polynomials. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume $X$ is compact, else it's false (typically $Hom(\pi_1(X), \Bbb C^*)$ is infinite dimensional if $X = \Bbb R^2 \backslash \Bbb Z$).

Now by standard topology $\pi_1(X)$ is finitely generated, say by $r$ elements : it follows that $\widehat G$ is a quotient of $(\Bbb C^*)^r$ by some relations, so it's a product between a torus and a finite group, in particular this is an affine algebraic group.

Comment: so if $G$ is a finitely generated group by $r$ elements then $\hat G$ is a quotient of  $(\mathbb C^*)^r$ by polynomial relations so it is a torus. Could you please explain these results or give me a reference. Thanks!

Comment: @palio : Since $\Bbb C^*$ is abelian, you have $Hom(\pi_1(X), \Bbb C^*) = Hom(H_1, \Bbb C^*)$ where $H_1$ is the abelianization of $\pi_1(X)$. So $H_1$ is a finitely generated abelian group, say $\Bbb Z^m \times F$ where $F$ is finite abelian. From this, $Hom(H_1, \Bbb C^*) \cong (\Bbb C^*)^m \times Hom(F, \Bbb C^*)$ which is the product of a torus with a finite group so it's an affine algebraic group.